# Showing how many days left of subscription from updated_at column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Subscription table that has plan_id and updated_at column. I can't figure out how to show the current user has x amount of days until subscription has ended.

plan_id 1 is a 30 day subscription.
plan_id 12 is a 12 month subscription.

Has someone done something similar to this?

Comment: Why would `updated_at` be related to the subscription expiration date?

Comment: @Mori It would be the time the subscription has started. So is the User is subscribed to `plan_id` 1, and the `updated_at` column is 2014-03-28 16:27:02. Then that subscription will end on 2014-04-28. Figured it would be easier to work from that column as opposed to making calls to Stripe/PayPal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a 'duration' column to the Plan model and set to appropriate number of days

i.e. 30 or 365

Add an expires_at method to your subscription:

```
class Subscription ...

  def expires_at
    self.created_at + plan.duration.days
  end

end
```

Use 'distance_of_time_in_words' to render appropriate text:

```
distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, subscription.expires_at)
```

Here is a link to the helper method:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words